# Hints on evaluating $\int_{0}^{k} x J_{n}^2(x) dx$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, bessel-functions

I am wondering how to do the integral $$\int_{0}^{k} u J_n^2({u}) du, \ n \in \mathbb{Z}^+,$$ and express my answer in terms of other first kind Bessel functions. I have searched [here](http://functions.wolfram.com/Bessel-TypeFunctions/BesselJ/20/ShowAll.html) for useful identities, but I can't seem to combine them in a way that helps.

Integration by parts hasn't proved to be useful either, since from what I've tried, I have to evaluate either $\int u J_{n}(u) du$ or $\int J_{n}(u)^2 du$, which both can't be expressed in terms of Bessel functions alone.

Does anyone have any hints? Thanks :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:**

Consider
$$\dfrac{d}{dx}\left[x^2\left(J_{n}^2(x)-J_{n+1}(x)J_{n-1}(x)\right)\right]$$
and prove
$$\int_{0}^{k} u J_n^2({u}) du=\dfrac12k^2\left(J_{n}^2(k)-J_{n+1}(k)J_{n-1}(k)\right)$$

Comment: I was typing the same when came your answer. What is "surprizing" is that it seems that, only for $k=2$, $\int u J_n^k({u}) du$ shows a nice expression in terms of Bessel functions. Do you know any reason for that ?